# Changing limit on number of downloads for past and future purchases - Downloadable Products

Tags: downloadable

I have a client with Downloadable Products on their Magento site.

Their Downloadable products are currently set at 5 downloads each. They want to increase this to 10 across the board for all past purchases, and all future purchases.

There are also some products/purchases with Unlimited downloads, which I don't want to touch.

I believe I have to run two SQL queries on the database to achieve this.

```
UPDATE downloadable_link SET number_of_downloads='10' WHERE number_of_downloads='5'
```

...to change the download limit on existing products (for future purchases)

```
UPDATE downloadable_link_purchased_item SET number_of_downloads_bought='10' WHERE number_of_downloads_bought='5'
```

...to change the download limit for past purchases.

Could someone reassure me this is all that needs to be done, or is there a better way?

The client has multiple websites so this applies to CE 1.8.1.0 and EE 1.14.0.1

Comment: Did you test this on a development environment? It seems fine but the only way to be sure is to test it out

Comment: Yes, I am testing it now and it seems to be OK. I know directly editing the DB is sometimes considered bad practice, but it seems to be the simplest option here. I didn't know if there was another method. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In this case it's probably the easiest way. As long as you test it you should be ok. Can you add your own solution as answer so we can close the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL queries in my question seem to work, and have the desired effect when tested.

```
UPDATE downloadable_link SET number_of_downloads='10' WHERE number_of_downloads='5'
```

AND

```
UPDATE downloadable_link_purchased_item SET number_of_downloads_bought='10' WHERE number_of_downloads_bought='5'
```

See original question for more explanation.